# Why does getattr catch all AttributeErrors and not just the attribute it's looking for?

Tags: python, getattr

The following is an issue I've observed in Python 3.8. Let's say I define a simple class:

```
class A:
    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.c # should throw AttributeError
```

Accessing `A().b` fails as expected (see below), but here's my issue:

```
>>> getattr(A(), 'b', 5)
5
```

Which essentially tells me that `getattr()` is the equivalent of:

```
def my_getattr_b(obj, default):
    try:
        return obj.b
    except AttributeError:
        # catches ANY missing attribute, not just b!
        return default
```

This makes me very nervous to use `getattr` in my code, because it can lead to completely incorrect behavior on a buggy class if it "fails" silently. The "correct" behavior ought to be that the exception is re-raised. Is the only safe solution the following?

```
def safe_getattr(obj, attr, default):
    if attr in dir(obj):
       # this will properly raise an AttributeError if something besides attr is missing
       return getattr(obj, attr) 
    else:
       return default
```

This works as expected:

```
>>> A().b
[...]
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'c'
```

This does too:

```
>>> getattr(A(), 'b')
[...]
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Comment: Maybe *don't pass a default?*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It looks like reason he's using `getattr()` is so he can specify a default.

Comment: The problem is that he wants a default for the `b` attribute, but the getter is getting an error for a different attribute, and this is being suppressed.

Comment: It's even worse than this example suggests. If the `b` getter gets an `AttributeError` on some completely unrelated object, it will still return the default. The documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr doesn't suggest any of this behavior.

Comment: Because the alternative would be substantially more complicated - what do you do, parse it out of the error message? What about custom implementations that don't have the default structure to the message? As far as the public API is concerned that attribute _is_ missing - when you try to access it, you get an AttributeError.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I wasn't clear on that point - that's *exactly* the issue I''m concerned about. Outside of this toy example, I came across this problem when a `getattr()` was obfuscating an unrelated AttributeError inside a property. The default value returned by `getattr` allowed the program to continue without crashing immediately, leading to a very hard-to-trace issue

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I suppose one pure-python alternative is what I have above as `safe_getattr()`, but it admittedly doesn't cover cases where e.g. `__getattr__()` is overridden. But I think @Barmar hit my problem on the head - the docs give no hint this is the expected behavior.

Comment: That's what it means to be a missing attribute in Python - you get an AttributeError when you try to access it. In a language with so much dynamic behaviour that's the only really meaningful definition. `dir`'s docs explicitly call out the shortcomings that are the reason your "safe" implementation isn't in use.

Comment: @snarayanan I think you've hit the underlying problem on the head. Because of `__getattr__()` and `__get()__`, `getattr()` can't tell whether the attribute really exists or not. All it knows is whether the exception was raised.

Comment: The issue of defining `safe_getattr` using `dir`, of course, is that classes and metaclasses can define custom `__dir__` methods... Quite difficult to think of a truly safe implementation that isn't hideously complex

Comment: Note this was reported and rejected: https://bugs.python.org/issue39865

Comment: Understood - the `dir` example was meant to be illustrative. It's definitely not a perfect (or even better) general solution. I guess at this point I'm satisfied that this the sanest implementation given the options, but I still think the docs ought to be far more explicit about this behavior.

Comment: @snarayanan, on that I agree with you!

Comment: I think the fundamental issue is as @jonrsharpe pointed out, as far as Python is concerned, if `some_object.some_attribute` raises an `AttributeError` for *any reason*, then that attribute *does not exist*